# How to push geoJSON data into empty arrays to construct multiple polygons on a google map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I am trying to draw multiple polygon's (shells) onto a google map.

I have at a problem:
A nested loop, which draws each polygon multiple times onto the map.

Besides that the code is working more or less.

Tried to put the empty array into different positions and to clear the content with each iteration - but somehow I couldn't find the right approach... feels like this loop should be built differently... :-)

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Simple Polygon</title>
            <style>

          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }

          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
       </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>



      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 9,
          center: {lat: 47.586, lng: 9},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });



       //Coordinates 
        const array = [
          [
         [
           47.42260606,
           9.367119279999999
         ],
        [
          47.4230557,
          9.36666964
        ],
        [
          47.4253039,
          9.36891784
        ],
        [
          47.4253039,
          9.372514959999998
        ],
        [
          47.42485426,
          9.3729646
        ],
        [
          47.42125714,
          9.3729646
        ],
        [
          47.4208075,
          9.372514959999998
        ],
        [
          47.4208075,
          9.37161568
        ],
        [
          47.419908219999996,
          9.3707164
        ],
        [
          47.419908219999996,
          9.36891784
        ],
        [
          47.42035786,
          9.368468199999999
        ],
        [
          47.42125714,
          9.368468199999999
        ],
        [
          47.42260606,
          9.367119279999999
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          47.450034099999996,
          9.418827879999998
        ],
        [
          47.45138302,
          9.420176799999998
        ],
        [
          47.45093338,
          9.420626439999998
        ],
        [
          47.44913482,
          9.420626439999998
        ],
        [
          47.4477859,
          9.419277519999998
        ],
        [
          47.44823554,
          9.418827879999998
        ],
        [
          47.450034099999996,
          9.418827879999998
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          47.52152686,
          9.421975359999998
        ],
        [
          47.5219765,
          9.421525719999998
        ],
        [
          47.52287578,
          9.421525719999998
        ],
        [
          47.52332542,
          9.421975359999998
        ],
        [
          47.52332542,
          9.422874639999998
        ],
        [
          47.5242247,
          9.423773919999999
        ],
        [
          47.5242247,
          9.425572479999998
        ],
        [
          47.52287578,
          9.426921399999998
        ],
        [
          47.52107722,
          9.426921399999998
        ],
        [
          47.5197283,
          9.425572479999998
        ],
        [
          47.5197283,
          9.422874639999998
        ],
        [
          47.520177939999996,
          9.422424999999999
        ],
        [
          47.52107722,
          9.422424999999999
        ],
        [
          47.52152686,
          9.421975359999998
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          47.510285859999996,
          9.427820679999998
        ],
        [
          47.51118514,
          9.428719959999999
        ],
        [
          47.51208442,
          9.428719959999999
        ],
        [
          47.51253406,
          9.429169599999998
        ],
        [
          47.51253406,
          9.430968159999997
        ],
        [
          47.515231899999996,
          9.433665999999999
        ],
        [
          47.51388298,
          9.435014919999999
        ],
        [
          47.5129837,
          9.435014919999999
        ],
        [
          47.51253406,
          9.435464559999998
        ],
        [
          47.51343334,
          9.436363839999999
        ],
        [
          47.51343334,
          9.437263119999997
        ],
        [
          47.5129837,
          9.437712759999998
        ],
        [
          47.51208442,
          9.437712759999998
        ],
        [
          47.51118514,
          9.436813479999998
        ],
        [
          47.510285859999996,
          9.437712759999998
        ],
        [
          47.5084873,
          9.437712759999998
        ],
        [
          47.50803766,
          9.437263119999997
        ],
        [
          47.50803766,
          9.436363839999999
        ],
        [
          47.5062391,
          9.434565279999998
        ],
        [
          47.5062391,
          9.432766719999998
        ],
        [
          47.50668874,
          9.432317079999997
        ],
        [
          47.50758802,
          9.432317079999997
        ],
        [
          47.50803766,
          9.431867439999998
        ],
        [
          47.50803766,
          9.430968159999997
        ],
        [
          47.50893694,
          9.430068879999999
        ],
        [
          47.50893694,
          9.428270319999998
        ],
        [
          47.50938658,
          9.427820679999998
        ],
        [
          47.510285859999996,
          9.427820679999998
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          47.45857726,
          9.426471759999998
        ],
        [
          47.45857726,
          9.427371039999999
        ],
        [
          47.4590269,
          9.427820679999998
        ],
        [
          47.46082546,
          9.427820679999998
        ],
        [
          47.46217438,
          9.429169599999998
        ],
        [
          47.46217438,
          9.430968159999997
        ],
        [
          47.4612751,
          9.431867439999998
        ],
        [
          47.4612751,
          9.433665999999999
        ],
        [
          47.45992618,
          9.435014919999999
        ],
        [
          47.45767798,
          9.432766719999998
        ],
        [
          47.45767798,
          9.429169599999998
        ],
        [
          47.4567787,
          9.428270319999998
        ],
        [
          47.4567787,
          9.426471759999998
        ],
        [
          47.45812762,
          9.425122839999998
        ],
        [
          47.45857726,
          9.425572479999998
        ],
        [
          47.45857726,
          9.426471759999998
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          47.49904486,
          9.436363839999999
        ],
        [
          47.4994945,
          9.435914199999997
        ],
        [
          47.50129306,
          9.435914199999997
        ],
        [
          47.5017427,
          9.436363839999999
        ],
        [
          47.50084342,
          9.437263119999997
        ],
        [
          47.50084342,
          9.438162399999998
        ],
        [
          47.50129306,
          9.438612039999997
        ],
        [
          47.50219234,
          9.438612039999997
        ],
        [
          47.50444054,
          9.440860239999997
        ],
        [
          47.50444054,
          9.442658799999998
        ],
        [
          47.50129306,
          9.445806279999998
        ],
        [
          47.49814558,
          9.442658799999998
        ],
        [
          47.49904486,
          9.441759519999998
        ],
        [
          47.49904486,
          9.440860239999997
        ],
        [
          47.49859522,
          9.440410599999998
        ],
        [
          47.49769594,
          9.440410599999998
        ],
        [
          47.49634702,
          9.439061679999998
        ],
        [
          47.49904486,
          9.436363839999999
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          47.49589738,
          9.453899799999997
        ],
        [
          47.4972463,
          9.455248719999998
        ],
        [
          47.4972463,
          9.457047279999998
        ],
        [
          47.49814558,
          9.457946559999998
        ],
        [
          47.49814558,
          9.459745119999997
        ],
        [
          47.49994414,
          9.461543679999997
        ],
        [
          47.49994414,
          9.463342239999998
        ],
        [
          47.49904486,
          9.464241519999998
        ],
        [
          47.49904486,
          9.467838639999997
        ],
        [
          47.49679666,
          9.470086839999997
        ],
        [
          47.49589738,
          9.470086839999997
        ],
        [
          47.49544774,
          9.470536479999998
        ],
        [
          47.49544774,
          9.471435759999997
        ],
        [
          47.4949981,
          9.471885399999998
        ],
        [
          47.4927499,
          9.469637199999998
        ],
        [
          47.4927499,
          9.468737919999997
        ],
        [
          47.49230026,
          9.468288279999998
        ],
        [
          47.49140098,
          9.468288279999998
        ],
        [
          47.48960242,
          9.470086839999997
        ],
        [
          47.48780386,
          9.470086839999997
        ],
        [
          47.48735422,
          9.469637199999998
        ],
        [
          47.4882535,
          9.468737919999997
        ],
        [
          47.4882535,
          9.463342239999998
        ],
        [
          47.48735422,
          9.462442959999997
        ],
        [
          47.48735422,
          9.458845839999997
        ],
        [
          47.48780386,
          9.458396199999997
        ],
        [
          47.48870314,
          9.458396199999997
        ],
        [
          47.48915278,
          9.457946559999998
        ],
        [
          47.48915278,
          9.455248719999998
        ],
        [
          47.48960242,
          9.454799079999997
        ],
        [
          47.4949981,
          9.454799079999997
        ],
        [
          47.49589738,
          9.453899799999997
        ]
      ]
    ]; 





    for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++){

    var shell = array[y];

        var latLngArray = [];

       for (var i = 0; i < shell.length; i++) {

          latLngArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(shell[i][0], shell[i][1]));


                // Polygon construction.
                 var ttPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                  paths: latLngArray,
                  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 0.2,
                  strokeWeight: 2,
                  fillColor: '#FF0000',
                  fillOpacity: 0.2
                  });
                  ttPoly.setMap(map);

             // latLngArray.length = 0

                }
          } 
  }   

        </script>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKey&callback=initMap">
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

How can I plot the polygon's only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently creating a new polygon for each coordinate.  Move the polygon creation outside of the loop that is creating the path array.  So:

for each polygon

1. create/clear out the path array.
2. parse its path into an array of `google.maps.LatLng` objects.
3. create a `google.maps.Polygon` object using that path.
4. add the polygon to the map.

```
// for each polygon in the array
for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++){
  var shell = array[y];
  var latLngArray = [];    
  // create path (array of LatLng objects) for this polygon
  for (var i = 0; i < shell.length; i++) {
    latLngArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(shell[i][0], shell[i][1]));
  }
  // create polygon with the path
  var ttPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: latLngArray,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.2
  });
  ttPoly.setMap(map);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z1809fcL/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: {
      lat: 47.586,
      lng: 9
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
    var shell = array[y];
    var latLngArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < shell.length; i++) {
      var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(shell[i][0], shell[i][1]);
      bounds.extend(pt);
      latLngArray.push(pt);
    }
    // Polygon construction.
    var ttPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: latLngArray,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.2,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.2
    });
    ttPoly.setMap(map);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
//Coordinates 
const array = [
  [
    [
      47.42260606,
      9.367119279999999
    ],
    [
      47.4230557,
      9.36666964
    ],
    [
      47.4253039,
      9.36891784
    ],
    [
      47.4253039,
      9.372514959999998
    ],
    [
      47.42485426,
      9.3729646
    ],
    [
      47.42125714,
      9.3729646
    ],
    [
      47.4208075,
      9.372514959999998
    ],
    [
      47.4208075,
      9.37161568
    ],
    [
      47.419908219999996,
      9.3707164
    ],
    [
      47.419908219999996,
      9.36891784
    ],
    [
      47.42035786,
      9.368468199999999
    ],
    [
      47.42125714,
      9.368468199999999
    ],
    [
      47.42260606,
      9.367119279999999
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      47.450034099999996,
      9.418827879999998
    ],
    [
      47.45138302,
      9.420176799999998
    ],
    [
      47.45093338,
      9.420626439999998
    ],
    [
      47.44913482,
      9.420626439999998
    ],
    [
      47.4477859,
      9.419277519999998
    ],
    [
      47.44823554,
      9.418827879999998
    ],
    [
      47.450034099999996,
      9.418827879999998
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      47.52152686,
      9.421975359999998
    ],
    [
      47.5219765,
      9.421525719999998
    ],
    [
      47.52287578,
      9.421525719999998
    ],
    [
      47.52332542,
      9.421975359999998
    ],
    [
      47.52332542,
      9.422874639999998
    ],
    [
      47.5242247,
      9.423773919999999
    ],
    [
      47.5242247,
      9.425572479999998
    ],
    [
      47.52287578,
      9.426921399999998
    ],
    [
      47.52107722,
      9.426921399999998
    ],
    [
      47.5197283,
      9.425572479999998
    ],
    [
      47.5197283,
      9.422874639999998
    ],
    [
      47.520177939999996,
      9.422424999999999
    ],
    [
      47.52107722,
      9.422424999999999
    ],
    [
      47.52152686,
      9.421975359999998
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      47.510285859999996,
      9.427820679999998
    ],
    [
      47.51118514,
      9.428719959999999
    ],
    [
      47.51208442,
      9.428719959999999
    ],
    [
      47.51253406,
      9.429169599999998
    ],
    [
      47.51253406,
      9.430968159999997
    ],
    [
      47.515231899999996,
      9.433665999999999
    ],
    [
      47.51388298,
      9.435014919999999
    ],
    [
      47.5129837,
      9.435014919999999
    ],
    [
      47.51253406,
      9.435464559999998
    ],
    [
      47.51343334,
      9.436363839999999
    ],
    [
      47.51343334,
      9.437263119999997
    ],
    [
      47.5129837,
      9.437712759999998
    ],
    [
      47.51208442,
      9.437712759999998
    ],
    [
      47.51118514,
      9.436813479999998
    ],
    [
      47.510285859999996,
      9.437712759999998
    ],
    [
      47.5084873,
      9.437712759999998
    ],
    [
      47.50803766,
      9.437263119999997
    ],
    [
      47.50803766,
      9.436363839999999
    ],
    [
      47.5062391,
      9.434565279999998
    ],
    [
      47.5062391,
      9.432766719999998
    ],
    [
      47.50668874,
      9.432317079999997
    ],
    [
      47.50758802,
      9.432317079999997
    ],
    [
      47.50803766,
      9.431867439999998
    ],
    [
      47.50803766,
      9.430968159999997
    ],
    [
      47.50893694,
      9.430068879999999
    ],
    [
      47.50893694,
      9.428270319999998
    ],
    [
      47.50938658,
      9.427820679999998
    ],
    [
      47.510285859999996,
      9.427820679999998
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      47.45857726,
      9.426471759999998
    ],
    [
      47.45857726,
      9.427371039999999
    ],
    [
      47.4590269,
      9.427820679999998
    ],
    [
      47.46082546,
      9.427820679999998
    ],
    [
      47.46217438,
      9.429169599999998
    ],
    [
      47.46217438,
      9.430968159999997
    ],
    [
      47.4612751,
      9.431867439999998
    ],
    [
      47.4612751,
      9.433665999999999
    ],
    [
      47.45992618,
      9.435014919999999
    ],
    [
      47.45767798,
      9.432766719999998
    ],
    [
      47.45767798,
      9.429169599999998
    ],
    [
      47.4567787,
      9.428270319999998
    ],
    [
      47.4567787,
      9.426471759999998
    ],
    [
      47.45812762,
      9.425122839999998
    ],
    [
      47.45857726,
      9.425572479999998
    ],
    [
      47.45857726,
      9.426471759999998
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      47.49904486,
      9.436363839999999
    ],
    [
      47.4994945,
      9.435914199999997
    ],
    [
      47.50129306,
      9.435914199999997
    ],
    [
      47.5017427,
      9.436363839999999
    ],
    [
      47.50084342,
      9.437263119999997
    ],
    [
      47.50084342,
      9.438162399999998
    ],
    [
      47.50129306,
      9.438612039999997
    ],
    [
      47.50219234,
      9.438612039999997
    ],
    [
      47.50444054,
      9.440860239999997
    ],
    [
      47.50444054,
      9.442658799999998
    ],
    [
      47.50129306,
      9.445806279999998
    ],
    [
      47.49814558,
      9.442658799999998
    ],
    [
      47.49904486,
      9.441759519999998
    ],
    [
      47.49904486,
      9.440860239999997
    ],
    [
      47.49859522,
      9.440410599999998
    ],
    [
      47.49769594,
      9.440410599999998
    ],
    [
      47.49634702,
      9.439061679999998
    ],
    [
      47.49904486,
      9.436363839999999
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      47.49589738,
      9.453899799999997
    ],
    [
      47.4972463,
      9.455248719999998
    ],
    [
      47.4972463,
      9.457047279999998
    ],
    [
      47.49814558,
      9.457946559999998
    ],
    [
      47.49814558,
      9.459745119999997
    ],
    [
      47.49994414,
      9.461543679999997
    ],
    [
      47.49994414,
      9.463342239999998
    ],
    [
      47.49904486,
      9.464241519999998
    ],
    [
      47.49904486,
      9.467838639999997
    ],
    [
      47.49679666,
      9.470086839999997
    ],
    [
      47.49589738,
      9.470086839999997
    ],
    [
      47.49544774,
      9.470536479999998
    ],
    [
      47.49544774,
      9.471435759999997
    ],
    [
      47.4949981,
      9.471885399999998
    ],
    [
      47.4927499,
      9.469637199999998
    ],
    [
      47.4927499,
      9.468737919999997
    ],
    [
      47.49230026,
      9.468288279999998
    ],
    [
      47.49140098,
      9.468288279999998
    ],
    [
      47.48960242,
      9.470086839999997
    ],
    [
      47.48780386,
      9.470086839999997
    ],
    [
      47.48735422,
      9.469637199999998
    ],
    [
      47.4882535,
      9.468737919999997
    ],
    [
      47.4882535,
      9.463342239999998
    ],
    [
      47.48735422,
      9.462442959999997
    ],
    [
      47.48735422,
      9.458845839999997
    ],
    [
      47.48780386,
      9.458396199999997
    ],
    [
      47.48870314,
      9.458396199999997
    ],
    [
      47.48915278,
      9.457946559999998
    ],
    [
      47.48915278,
      9.455248719999998
    ],
    [
      47.48960242,
      9.454799079999997
    ],
    [
      47.4949981,
      9.454799079999997
    ],
    [
      47.49589738,
      9.453899799999997
    ]
  ]
];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```